# How do I see which questions I've flagged?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I flagged a question as low quality, but nevertheless, I may in the future want to revisit that question. It's not a problem now, because the question is still on the first page, but in the future, can I see a list of questions I've flagged? I've been looking on my profile, especially the [activity tab](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/7590/john-bensin?tab=activity&sort=all) but I can't seem to find a place to see this list.

I'm sure it's simple, but I haven't been able to find it.

EDIT: Here is a screenshot of my profile summary:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your profile page, look in the *stats* section (to the right of your profile picture) for *helpful flags*. It should show just beneath *profile views* in the *stats* section, as in the example here:

[image: Example of stats section including helpful flag count and link]

Notice that the number of helpful flags is a link.  When you click that link, you'll see your flag history page.

(FWIW, you'll see *helpful flags* only on your own profile.  If you look at another user's profile, the *stats* section will only show *profile views*.)

Comment: Perhaps it's because I've only flagged one question, but I don't see helpful flags listed anywhere. I updated my question with a screenshot. The question seems to have been deleted too (I can't see any of my activity related to it in my profile). Could that be the reason?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135937/dont-see-the-helpful-flags-link-on-my-profile

Comment: Ah, ok. According to [my flag page](http://money.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/7590), the flag I raised was disputed, so that's why it isn't showing up. (I don't think you can access that link, but I included it just so I'll remember where to find it).